# Google Drive v3 Resumable Upload

Tags: vb.net, google-drive-api

I am trying to figure out how to use Google drive v3 resumable upload on vb.net to upload big files.

I've checked this https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/resumable-upload and was able to upload small files using basic upload but can't find any code samples for resumable upload using vb.net.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it done, here's the final code in case somebody else needs:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports System.Net.Http.Headers
Imports System.Threading
Imports Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2
Imports Google.Apis.Drive.v3
Imports Google.Apis.Services
Imports Google.Apis.Upload
Imports Google.Apis.Util.Store

Module Module1
    Dim credential As UserCredential
    Dim ApplicationName As String = "NET"
    Dim Scopes As String() = {DriveService.Scope.Drive}
    Sub Main()

        Using stream = New FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
            Dim credPath As String = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json")

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, Scopes, "user", CancellationToken.None, New FileDataStore(credPath, True)).Result
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString("Credential file saved to: ") & credPath)
        End Using

        Dim service = New DriveService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With {
            .HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            .ApplicationName = ApplicationName
        })


        Task.Run(Async Function()
                     Await UploadFileAsync(service, credential.Token.AccessToken, "welcome.mp4", "video/mp4", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt"))
                 End Function).GetAwaiter().GetResult()


        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...")
        Console.ReadKey()

    End Sub


    Private Async Function UploadFileAsync(service As DriveService, accessToken As String, filePath As String, mimeType As String, newFileName As String) As Task(Of Boolean)
        Dim uri As Uri
        Dim uploadStream = New System.IO.FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read)

        Using client = New HttpClient()
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Upload-Content-Type", mimeType)
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Upload-Content-Length", uploadStream.Length.ToString())
            Dim request = New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable")
            request.Content = New StringContent("{""name"": """ + newFileName + """, ""parents"":[""folder_id_goes_here""]}")
            request.Content.Headers.ContentType = New MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json")
            Dim response = Await client.SendAsync(request)
            uri = response.Headers.Location
        End Using

        Dim uploader = ResumableUpload.CreateFromUploadUri(uri, uploadStream, New ResumableUploadOptions())
        AddHandler uploader.ProgressChanged, AddressOf Upload_ProgressChanged

        Dim progress As IUploadProgress
        progress = Await uploader.UploadAsync()
        If progress.Status <> UploadStatus.Completed Then
            While (Await uploader.ResumeAsync()).Status <> UploadStatus.Completed
                Await Task.Delay(10000)
            End While
        End If
        uploadStream.Dispose()
        Return True
    End Function

    Private Sub Upload_ProgressChanged(progress As IUploadProgress)
        Console.WriteLine(progress.Status.ToString() & " " & progress.BytesSent)
    End Sub

End Module
```